# RestSharp GetOrPost Parameter Culture

Tags: restsharp

Is there any chance to enforce a default culture for GetOrPost parameter serialization without changing the Thread Culture?
On my italian-based machine, decimal are serialized with comma while I'd need dots.

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: There is no property for the culture and current thread culture change seems to be the way to go.

Comment: I encpsulated those parameters in custom types,  overriding the ToString method.